# Using Silverlight RIA Services DomainDataSource to query by user

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, domaindatasource

So I am using the SL4 Business Template and the SQL Membership API. I created a user and I created a custom table that ties to that user.

So I want to have a datagrid that show the item for the CURRENT (WebContext.Current.User) user.

1. Why is the GUID for the user in WebContext.Current.User??? I need that to join to the 'Items' table.
2. How can I use the XAML DomainDatasource... from what I see you can only use it if you can bind to something else on the XAML.. for example if I have a calendar control on the page I can bind the domaindatasource to the calendar.... But I want to query giving the 'UserID (GUID)'... so do I need to put a hidden field on the XAML with that value to have access to it? (like the hidden fileds in asp.net)

or am I going about it all the wrong way... its a really simple conceopt.. I have users.. I have items.. there is a relationship.. and I want a datagrid filled with items for a particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this. First, you could just write a query GetDataForCurrentUser() and pull the current user on the server. This tends to be the more secure option since a user can only get their own data. The second option is to pass the user guid as a parameter. In this post, I show a couple ways to do just that.

http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/03/18/custom-filter-parameter.aspx

Comment: im confused at first glance... you are talking about getting the UserID GUID using forms authentication + the built in SQL membership tables right?  ill look at your code more clsely tomorrow.

Comment: I look into it more.. I still don't get it.. 

I used the code from your sample to pass the User.Name...

But what I want is the PrimaryKey which is the User GUID... how do I get that value???

I need that key to then match up the user with 'Items' 

This seems like such a commmon thing to do with the SQL Membership tables I dunno why it seems hard to me.

Comment: Sorry. I assumed you were familiar with the RIA authentication support. If that isn't the case, you can start with a tutorial (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707361(v=VS.91).aspx) or some samples (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2661).

Comment: Also, User.Name should be treated as the unique user identifier (primary key). It sounds like it would be best if it had the User GUID in it.

Comment: so... I need to figure out how to get the GUID property in the User object... The seems to be the missing piece of the puzzle im not understanding?

Comment: did you mean 'should' or 'should not'

Comment: It 'should' be a unique identifier. It's a side-effect of implementing the IPrincipal interface (typically the name is associated with your login name). If your identifier is a guid, use that. If you want to store the user's name somewhere, add another property and put it in your tables or add it as a profile property.